# Publish or undeploy promotion via a cronjob in Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

I would like to publish or undeploy promotions which is built on the new promotion engine (rule base) via a cronjob according to dates that determine in the backoffice as a seperate model that has promotion code, start date and end date.

I could not find the promotion api in help hybris to perform publish and undeploy operations like in the backoffice. And also I could not find related promotion services in the project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an exemple to publish promotions in Groovy :

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry
def activateAllPromotions()
{
    def maintenanceService = Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("ruleMaintenanceService")
    def ruleService = Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("ruleService")
    def rules = ruleService.getAllRules()
    def res = maintenanceService.compileAndPublishRules(rules,"promotions-module",true)
}
activateAllPromotions()
```

You can unpublish using `maintenanceService#archiveRule(AbstractRuleModel)`

Comment: FYI, the groovy console in the hac provides the spring context via the variable `spring`. So instead of `Registry...` you could use `spring.getBean('...')`

Answer (score 1):

For publishing promotions you can use:

```
ruleMaintenanceService.compileAndPublishRules(promotions,"promotions-module",true);
```

For unpublishing promotions you can use:

```
ruleMaintenanceService.undeployRules(promotions,site);
```

Comment: `compileAndPublishRules` doesn't work for me. This compiles the rule, but does not publish it. In BO I see compiled rules with incremented version and status is `inactive`.
How can i get this to work?
Thanks!

UPD: I'm a stupid. When the rule is saved, a new version of it is created automatically. And it should be published.